# ASP.NET MVC with SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

Hi I want to create a model with out using ORM to save it into the SQL Server. Is it possible? And I want to use stored procedures. How can I do that. Can anyone help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Siva

Comment: Can You describe how do You imagine saving a model into SQL without ORM? Did I miss something?

Comment: I have done with ORM mapping. So I want to try with out using ORM. ORM having the table properties. So as like that can we create the class for the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORM simply means Object Relational Mapping.

One thing you could do, and I would recommended against, is to create some classes that are complete ignorant of their database properties, and create methods for saving or updating into the database based on parameters you choose and using the SqlCommand class to issue the command to execute those stored procedures.

All of the methods for direct manipulation of data to and from a SQL database are found in the [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8t72t3k4.aspx).  You will need to deal directly with DataReaders and all the other wonderful * cough * things that ORMs have abstracted away for us.

You'd be better off using Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL, or nHibernate.

Comment: I agree that you are better off sticking with using some sort of ORM, as they take away a lot of the pain that you will need to endure y not using them.

Comment: Ya thanks ron. I'll follow that.